# Multiple Image Uploading with Reduce with php CodeIgniter

Tags: php

i want reduce images while uploading.
here is my image upload code.

html

```
<div id="filediv"><input  name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div>
```

php

```
$file_slider_orginal_name = [];
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 
    $is_updated = 0;
    $target_path = substr(BASEPATH, 0, -7) . "../../../images/Slider_images/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable
        $imageName = date("Ymd") . $t . $i . "." . $file_extension; //set the target path with a new name of image
        $target_path = $target_path . $imageName; //set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1; //increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
            $is_updated = 1;
        } else {
            $is_updated = 0;
        }

        if ($is_updated == 1) {
            $i_name = explode("/", $target_path, 10);

            $file_slider_orginal_name[$i] = $i_name[9];
        }
    }
```

this code is most suitable for upload but i want reduce image while upload.
can i help for reduce image while uploading.
Thank you.

Comment: why you don't want use library('upload') in   codeignaiter

Comment: check this http://www.onlinecode.org/multiple-file-upload-codeigniter-example/

Comment: Thanks for answers.my problem is resolved.

Comment: Dave your link is most helpful for me.Thanks again.